# cakephp show entries per month

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following script which shows me 5 recent invoices as below:

```
<?php 
  $year = (int)(substr($invoice['Invoice']['invoice_date'], 0, -6));
  $month = (int)(substr($invoice['Invoice']['invoice_date'], 5, -3));
?>
<?php if($count < 5) : ?>
```

This now shows the 5 latest invoices, no matter which month they are due. How can I tweak / alter this snippet to showcase me the 5 invoices for the current month?

Answer (score 3):

Why not to use `cakephp time helper`.

```
<?php $year  = $time->format('Y',$invoice['Invoice']['invoice_date']); ?>
<?php $month = $time->format('m',$invoice['Invoice']['invoice_date']); ?>
```

And for your latest record of this month try below solution.

```
<?php

$this->Invoice->find('all', array
(
    'conditions'=> array('DATE_FORMAT(Invoice.invoice_date,"%m") = "'.date("m").'"')
));
```

Comment: `$time->` should be `$this->Time->` !

Comment: hummm but when we can access it in view file i don't think we need $this..because i tried without $this and its worked..

Comment: its still what I just said for all cake versions >= 1.3. Before that it was the old syntax. and even if it might work it is deprecated and can and will stop working with an upgrade. So I see no point in writing outdated and potentially wrong answers.

Comment: thanx for information mark..really appreciate it...learn something new today.